# Return name user machine .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-server-2008

I have a problem, I work with visual 2010 frame 3.5 my project is built in in windows server 2008.

The problem code:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string variableUsuario = user.Name.ToUpper();
```

With this code in my localhost or visual,I want to obtain the machine user name, but it does not work.  In the server, return this text :

```
.IIS APPPOOL\PROYECTOSIGEV
```

PROYECTOSIGEV is the name of the project

Answer (score 2):

That's because the application pool, on IIS, is running under that identity. If you need to get the Windows user name you'll need to enable [Windows Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) on the application pool. ***NOTE:*** by enabling Windows Authentication on IIS, you don't need to change your code.

Comment: where is this option ? i don't find

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the page I linked to? There is a heading titled `To use the UI` and it walks you through enabling Windows Authentication on IIS. If you're running IIS 6 then use this document (http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5f8fe119-4095-4094-bba5-7dec361c7afe.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: mmm i see thi link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx because i work iis 7, but dont not show the " 3.On the Authentication page, select Windows Authentication. " option

Answer (score 0):

I've used;

- System.Environment.UserName
- HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", False))